# How to add data to state object in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I created `this.state.data` object. Now I need to put `this.state.email` and this.state.password into `this.state.data.email2` and `this.state.data.password2`

I want to create local storage. To do that I need an object where I could store data. `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` are inputs.

```
class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      data: {
        email2: '',
        password2: '',
      },
    }

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback 
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }

  handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }
  handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);

    /*
    Take values from input, ant put it into this state data array
    */

  // Reset form;
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
    })
  }
```

When I activate `handleSubmit` method I expect to take `this.state.email`, and `this.state.password`. And put it into object `this.state.data`

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with storing them to data object?

Comment: "// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback " you don't need to bind those arrow functions.

Comment: I'm not sure how. In handleEmailChange i can't put this.setState({data.email2}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you need to pass `this.state.email and this.state.password` to `this.state.data`

You can do that in `handleEmailChange` and `handlePasswordChange` itself, and your using arrow functions, so don't need to bind this in constructor.

Check a code below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      data: {
        email2: '',
        password2: '',
      },
    }
  }
   handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      email: event.target.value,
      data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        email2: event.target.value,
      }  
    });
  }
  handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value,
      data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        password2: event.target.value,
      } 
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);
    console.log('object data');
     console.log(this.state.data);

    /*
    Take values from input, ant put it into this state data array
    */

  // Reset form;
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} value={this.state.email} />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} value={this.state.password} />
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zmbnup)

and don't need to write separate events for similar functionalities, Check the demo once, you can do it like below:

```
<input type="text" data-field = "email" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />
<input type="text"  data-field = "password" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.password} />
```

and in `handleChange`

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
     [event.target.getAttribute('data-field')]: event.target.value,
      data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        [`${event.target.getAttribute('data-field')}2`]: event.target.value,
      }  
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (assuming your setup supports spread operator `...` )

```
handleEmailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
    this.setState(prevState => ({ data: { ...prevState.data, email2: event.target.value } }));
};
handlePasswordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
    this.setState(prevState => ({ data: { ...prevState.data, password2: event.target.value } }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);

    const {data} = this.state;
    data.email2 = this.state.email;
    data.password2 = this.state.password;
    this.setState({ data  });

// Reset form;
    this.setState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    })
}
```

or without mutating the state (good practice)

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: {
        ...prevState.data,
        [data.email2]: this.state.email
        [data.password2]: this.state.password
    },
   }));
```

Comment: try the other solution as it is good practice to not mutate the state